# Does setting a --proxy-server header work in chromeless?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer, chromeless

I'm trying to set the proxy server for a chromeless implementation on Lambda using the setExtraHTTPHeaders setter like:

```
await chromeless
       .setExtraHTTPHeaders({
                            '--proxy-server': 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx:80'
                            });
```

After merging I also tried by using:

```
chromeFlags: ['--proxy-server=xxx.xxx.xx.xx:80']
```

But the IP address is still the AWS IP.  Does this setter not work or am I missing something?